# T-SQL select specific number from string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help with query. I have string:

```
"ABC xx DEF SERVERxx ASDF xxx days."
```

where `x` is number (0 to 9 can appear anywhere within string).

I am interested in the number just before "days." it can be anywhere from 7 to 999999...

String always ends with "days."

I was trying to make something out of this:

```
 Select Left(SubString(Data, PatIndex(‘%[0-9.-]%’, Data), 8000), PatIndex(‘%[^0-9.-]%’, SubString(Data, PatIndex(‘%[0-9.-]%’, Data), 8000) + ‘X’)-1)
```

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/

with no luck so far as it grabs first number in the string.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I just want to clarify "ABC xx DEF SERVERxx ASDF" is random text with numbers in side and varies in length. The only constant is number before "days." at the end of string. Number can be any number.

Comment: Too bad I am too slow (it is hot in my apartment), but if you use tokens and compare the next values from that token (since ' days' is set), you can make the code robust and not long at all.

Comment: in postgresql I would use regex:  `select substring(substring( 'ABC 12 DEF SERVER32 ASDF 100 days 2131 foo' from e'[0-9.]+ days\.$' ),'[0-9.]+');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not overly efficient, reversing the string, removing the leading space and substringing will accomplish this:

```
select reverse(substring(ltrim(replace(reverse(COLUMN), '.syad','')),0, charindex(' ', ltrim(replace(reverse(COLUMN), '.syad','')))))
```

Working example:

```
declare @v as  varchar(500)

select @v = 'ABC xx DEF SERVERxx ASDF 952 days.'

select reverse(substring(ltrim(replace(reverse(@v), '.syad','')),0, charindex(' ', ltrim(replace(reverse(@v), '.syad','')))))
```

Comment: @ArunasT Feel free to mark my answer if it worked out for you.  Glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Since the max characters ,you can have is 999999 before days,what you can do is get all 11 characters from right,You also need [numbers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) table.  Then you have to

1.Replace spaces.
2.check if each character is int or not using numbers table
3.Finally use XML path to combine multiple rows to single row

Create this as userdefined function and try to use it..

**Function:**

```
;With cte
as
(
select 
  try_convert(int,substring(right(replace(@string,' ',''),11),number,1)) as item
from numbers n
where number<=11
)
select 
STUFF
(
(
select
'' +cast(item as varchar(2))
from cte
where item is not null
for xml path('')
)
,1,0,'')
```

**Some tests:**
Input as least number

```
declare @string varchar(max)='ABC xx DEF SERVERxx ASDF 1 days'
```

**Output:** 1

**Maximum input:**
declare @string varchar(max)='ABC xx DEF SERVERxx ASDF 999999 days'

**Output:**  999999

**Update:**
 Assuming dbo.getdata() is the scalar function i have created for this,to use this in below select

```
select * from test
```

all i have to do is

```
select *,dbo.getdata(columnname) from test
```

Comment: Did you accounted that xx and SERVERxx is also a number? And I am not a super SQL user so I can't validate your solution, not sure how to use it.

Comment: yes ,this accounts for all and it gets number before days as long it is between 1 and 999999

Comment: Here is my select statement: Select 
Alert.vAlert.AlertDescription from Alert.vAlert. How do I use it with your function? @TheGameiswar

Answer (score 1):

If the string always ends with "days." and you want the digits immediately preceding it (whereupon the value "days." is irrelevant), then you want the *first* sequence of digits in the *reverse* of the string.

Showing it in steps:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @s = 'ABC 12 DEF SERVER34 ASDF 56789 days.';

DECLARE @t VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @t = REVERSE(@s);

DECLARE @firstDigit BIGINT;
DECLARE @lastDigit BIGINT;
DECLARE @afterDigit VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @firstDigit = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @t);

SELECT @afterDigit = RIGHT(@t, LEN(@t) - @firstDigit);
SELECT @lastDigit = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @afterDigit) + @firstDigit;

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@t, @firstDigit, @lastDigit - @firstDigit + 1));
```

Or substituting the variables into the last line:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @s = 'ABC 12 DEF SERVER34 ASDF 5627891 days.';

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@s), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@s)), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', RIGHT(REVERSE(@s), LEN(REVERSE(@s)) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@s)))) + PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@s)) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@s)) + 1));
```

Just replace all seven occurences of `@s` with your column name.

It might be better to pre-process the data if you need to use the value frequently.

Comment: I am not sure how to validate this either. Here is my Select statement: Select 
Alert.vAlert.AlertDescription
from Alert.vAlert

Comment: @ArunasT You can enter the above directly as a query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), and click the "Execute" button. I tested it myself with various data in place of "56789", such as "1", "999999", "5678910".

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max) = 'ABC xx DEF SERVERxx ASDF 203.5 knots' select reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(@str),charindex(' ',REVERSE(@str)),(charindex(' ',REVERSE(@str),charindex(' ',REVERSE(@str))+1)-charindex(' ',REVERSE(@str)))))
```

---

[image]

result=203.5

Comment: This didn't work as "ABC xx" or "SERVERxx" - x's are numbers.

Comment: can you plz provide the sample which you have tried. please see the above image

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by using a simple substring function as below

    `DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max) = 'ABC xx DEF SERVERxx ASDF xxx days'
    DECLARE @locationOfDays INT 
    DECLARE @locationOfASDF INT
    SELECT @locationOfDays = CHARINDEX('days',@s)
    SELECT @locationOfASDF = CHARINDEX('ASDF',@s)
    select @locationOfASDF,@locationOfDays
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@s,@locationOfASDF+4+1, @locationOfDays-@locationOfASDF-1-4-1)`

The way logic to this is to get the location of Days and ASDF first
which will be done using CHARINDEX function and stored in thier respective variables.
Then you can start using the SUBSTRING function to get the exact thing you need, you need to add 4+1 to the start position as 4 is the length of ASDF and 1 for space, you need to substract the same from the length parameter of substring again, and one more 1 subtraction for the extra space.

Comment: I think that "ASDF" is placeholder text for an unknown string.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't bother answering question when they already have this many  answers already that seems to be working, but I think there is an easier way to solve this problem then what was introduced in the other answers, so here is my solution:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 'ABC 12 DEF SERVER78 ASDF 384684 days.'

SELECT RIGHT(
        LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 6), -- remove the ' days.' part
            PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', 
            REVERSE(
                LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 6) -- remove the ' days.' part
            ) -- Reversing this string - it now starts with the number
        ) -- get the index of the first non-digit char after your desired number
    )
```

Result:

```
 384684
```

The key to this solution is to first remove the ' days.' from the end of the string, using the `LEFT()` function. Then, use the `PATINDEX()` function on the reversed string (using `REVERSE()`) to find the index first non-digit character in the reversed string. Finally, use this value with the `RIGHT()` function to return only the relevant number.

<kbd>[See live demo here](http://rextester.com/YUPBG95636)</kbd>

Comment: As-is didn't work. I see duplicate "LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 6), -- remove the ' days.' part"

Comment: Worked for me. Will test again hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: Tested again. seems to be working fine. Added a link to a live demo. 
The reason you see the `LEFT(@String...` part twice is because once I'm using it for the `PATINDEX` and once for the `RIGHT`.